# Enviar PDF em Anexo mPDF, phpmailer

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer, mpdf

Tenho o seguinte código em PHP:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
$this->load->helper('mpdf');
$this->data['dadosboleto'] = $this->boleto_model->GerarBoletoCEF($id_cliente, $data_inicial, $data_final);
$this->data['view'] = 'boleto/boleto';
$html = $this->load->view('boleto/boleto_impressao', $this->data, true);
pdf_create($html, 'boleto_'.$id_cliente."_". date('d-m-Y'), true);
```

Preciso que ao invés de gerar e forçar o download do PDF (boleto), gostaria de enviar este boleto em anexo para um e-mail. Só não sei como transformar ele em arquivo, o envio eu sei desenvolver.

Comment: Acho que pode ser um caminho : http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdf.examples-basic.php

Comment: Este link faz exatamente isso. https://gist.github.com/ajitbohra/3eb0296265931ddb4e84